# Track copying excel file

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to track if anyone saving as an excel file using VBA?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can add macro to workbooksave and write to veryhidden worksheet data about saving user/computer  (environ function)

Comment: Only if they are doing save as i need to track not all the time file is being saved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Use the [Workbook.BeforeSave Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbook.BeforeSave) which occurs before the workbook is saved.

Then write a log in whatever way you prefer. Eg log into a text file or in a worksheet of the workbook itself.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    If SaveAsUI Then
        ' do Stuff for SaveAs
    Else
        ' do stuff for Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH :) But i want to track if the file only being saved as in another name!!